# Doing math with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

```
var num1 = $("input[id='weight']").val(),
    num2 = $("input[id='height']").val(),
    result = num1 / (num2*num2);

$("#submit").click(function() {
    $(".result").text(result);
});
```

It's just displaying `NaN` where the result should be. Why?

Answer (score 4):

You should get the values inside the click event, not when the page loads:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var num1 = $("input[id='weight']").val(),
    num2 = $("input[id='height']").val(),
    result = num1 / (num2*num2);
  $(".result").text(result);
});
```

There are also some other reasons why you might `NaN` as result:

- The height field evaluates to zero. (Although that would normally give the result `Infinity` rather than `NaN`.)
- Some of the fields contains something that can't be converted to a number.
- You have used the wrong names in the code, so you don't actually get the values from the fields.
- You are using floating point numbers with the wrong decimal separator, e.g. `0.5` when the browsers expects `0,5`, or vice versa.

Some notes:

- It's good practice to parse the strings using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` (which ever is appropriate) before doing the calculations.
- Consider if using a selector like `input#weight` or just `#weight` would work. You would only need to use a selector like `input[id='weight']` if you have multiple elements with the same id in the page, and that is not recommended.

Comment: +1, i know this is such a shame, but i'm discovering right now that 0 produce NaN! =)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var num1   = $("#weight").val(), 
            num2   = $("#height").val(), 
            result = num1 / (num2 * num2);
        $(".result").text(result);
    }); 
});
```

little explanation:

the problem is not to parseInt here. IMHO the problem is that at the moment of the math the two vars are empty or not a number...

Comment: Note: The selector `#weight` doesn't do the same thing as `input[id='weight']`. Not even `input#weight` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: and we have a winner! Thank you very much everybody!

Comment: @Guffa : my assumption was that each id should be unique per page?

Comment: @aSeptik: Yes, the id should be unique, but that isn't always the case in reality...

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to integers (assuming you're using integers):

```
var num1 = parseInt($("#weight").val(), 10),
    num2 = parseInt($("#height").val(), 10),
    result = num1 / (num2*num2);
```

Comment: Note: The selector `#weight` doesn't do the same thing as `input[id='weight']`. Not even `input#weight` does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var num1 = parseInt($("input[id='weight']").val());
num2 = parseInt($("input[id='height']").val());
result = num1 / (num2*num2);

$("#submit").click(function() {
$(".result").text(result);
});
```

Comment: I would recommend always specifying the radix